# Finite dimension and total boundedness

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

Let $T:X\to Y$ be a bounded operator between Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$. Assume that for any $\epsilon >0$ there is a finite-dimensional subspace $Y_\epsilon\subset Y$ so that $\|Q_\epsilon T\|<\epsilon$, where $Q_\epsilon : Y\to Y/Y_\epsilon$ is the quotient map.
Define
$$K=\{y\in Y_\epsilon : dist(y, T(B(0,1))<\epsilon\}$$
(here $B(0,1)$ indicates the unit ball in $X$)

Then the text I am reading says 
"$K$ is bounded and thus, as $dim Y_\epsilon <\infty$, totally bounded".

I do not see why, does someone has any hint?
Thanks

Paola

Comment: A finite-dimensional Hausdorff topological vector space is isomorphic to $\mathbb{K}^n$, where $n$ is the dimension and $\mathbb{K}$ the scalar field, be it real or complex. Isomorphic means "as topological vector spaces" here. In $\mathbb{K}^n$, you know that every closed and bounded set is compact (Heine-Borel), whence every bounded set is a subset of a compact set. Since compact sets are totally bounded, and total boundedness is inherited by subsets, the claim follows.

Comment: Thank you, I see your point but the thing here is that I interpret that "bounded" as bounded in $Y$ and not in $Y_\epsilon$. $T$ is bounded so we know $T(B(0,1))$ is contained in, say, $B_Y(0,R)$ for a certain $R$. hence our $K\subset B_Y(0,R+2\epsilon)$.
Is it me just getting confused or what?

Comment: For subsets of $Y_\epsilon$, the notions of "bounded in $Y$" and "bounded in $Y_\epsilon$" coincide. First, $Y_\epsilon$ inherits the (restriction of the) norm of $Y$, and that makes the two notions immediately identical for subsets of $Y_\epsilon$. Then the noteworthy fact that a finite-dimensional Hausdorff TVS is isomorphic (as a topological vector space) to $\mathbb{K}^n$ kicks in, and tells you that all closed and bounded subsets of $Y_\epsilon$ are compact, hence all bounded subsets relatively compact, hence totally bounded.

Comment: $K$ is defined as a subset of $Y_\epsilon$, if you have overlooked that. $K = Y_\epsilon \cap (T(B_X(0,1)) + B_Y(0,\epsilon))$.

Answer (score 1):

Since dim $Y_\varepsilon < \infty$  and $K$ is bounded,  $\overline{K}$ in $Y_\varepsilon$ is compact and we can take a finite subcover of $\cup_{y\in K} B(y,\delta)$, for all $\delta>0$.